# Need help resolving dependency installation error after using --force flag for MUI

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I was getting the error while installing mui so , i install mui using --force flag . After that  every package that I am trying to install it gives me same error . Now for every package its is required  to use --force flag

can anyone help me in removing this issue

```
   C:\Users\har\Desktop\proj_frontend> npm i eslint
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/styles@5.15.6
    npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.3
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
    npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
    npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
    npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.15.6
    npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
   npm ERR!         peer @mui/material@"^5.0.0" from @mui/icons-material@5.15.6
    npm ERR!         node_modules/@mui/icons-material
    npm ERR!         2 more (@mui/x-date-pickers, the root project)
    npm ERR!       4 more (@mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, @mui/x-date-pickers, the root project)
    ....

    npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.0" from @mui/styles@5.15.6
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@mui/styles
    npm ERR!     @mui/styles@"^5.15.0" from the root project
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! For a full report see:
    npm ERR! C:\Users\har\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-11T06_30_10_343Z-eresolve-report.txt
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\har\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-11T06_30_10_343Z-debug-0.log
```

i tried to clear cache but the issue is same

```
 PS C:\Users\har\Desktop\proj_frontend> npm cache clean --force
    npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
    
  PSC:\Users\har\Desktop\proj_frontend> npm init @eslint/config
    √ How would you like to use ESLint? · problems
    √ What type of modules does your project use? · esm
    √ Which framework does your project use? · react
    √ Does your project use TypeScript? · No / Yes
    √ Where does your code run? · browser
    √ What format do you want your config file to be in? · JavaScript
    Local ESLint installation not found.
    The config that you've selected requires the following dependencies:
    
    eslint-plugin-react@latest eslint@latest
    √ Would you like to install them now? · No / Yes
    √ Which package manager do you want to use? · npm
    Installing eslint-plugin-react@latest, eslint@latest
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! While resolving: @mui/styles@5.15.6
    npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.3
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
    npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
    npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
    npm ERR!       peerOptional @emotion/styled@"^11.3.0" from @mui/material@5.15.6
    npm ERR!       node_modules/@mui/material
   
   ......
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\har\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-11T06_39_49_435Z-debug-0.log
    Successfully created .eslintrc.js file in
```

Comment: What was the initial reason for using force when installing MUI?

Comment: iniial reason is same error which i am getting now